# .htaccess redirect directory to file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

How do you redirect a directory (in this case `/resume/`) to a file (`/Resume.pdf`) using an .htaccess file? I have tried different rewrite methods but keep getting a redirect loop. Is this because of a conflict with WordPress?

This doesn't seem to work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^resume/ http://domain.com/Resume.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Clear your cache, then try again. I think a previous, wrong attempt, is cached. This particular setup works for me. The first rule redirects. The second rule does not match anymore then. The third rule does not match either, because resume.pdf is a file.

Comment: I cleared caches in both Chrome and Firefox and still getting 404's on both browsers.

Comment: 404 is something else than a redirect loop. 404 means that you either entered the url wrong, or there is simply no file where you expect it to be.

Comment: Is `/resume/` a directory? What is location of this .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava No it's not a directory but a shortcut or alias to a PDF file. The .htaccess is stored in the root same as the resume PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out and here's what I got to work:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/resume$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/Resume.pdf [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```